# How to set default value for Map in spring @Value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hashmap

I am having below property in properties file

```
test.feature={UPPER:{id:'54'}}
```

Below is the bean I am tying to get the value from properties file.

```
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> test(
        @Value("#{${test.feature}}")
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> ids) {

        return ids;
    }
```

It's working fine. But if we not configure the property, want to set the default value.

I tried in different ways but nothing helps.

```
@Value("#{${test.feature:{T(java.util.Collections).emptyMap()}}}")
getting IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found. 

@Value("#{${test.feature} ?: { : }}")

@Value("#{${test.feature:}}")
```

I have tried above ways but nothing helps.

Note: I'm using spring 5.x and not in spring boot.

How to fix this?

Comment: `if (ids == null || ids.isEmpty()) ids = Map.of("foo", "bar"); return ids; `!?

Comment: but +1 for (ease&pragmatism) doing "(sort of) json in properties" ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the map is not empty, it can be written as follows:

```
@Value("#{${populate.map:{'k1':'v1','k2':'v2'}}}")  // result is {"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}
private Map<String, String> map3;
```

or:

```
@Value("#{${test.feature:{k1:{nk1:'v1'}}}}") Map<String,Map<String,String>> map
```

otherwise:

```
@Value("#{${test.feature:{T(java.util.Collections).emptyMap()}}}") Map<String, String> map3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**1. This is how you can define map in .properties file**

```
myMap.key1 = value1

myMap.key2 = value2

myMap.key3 = value3
```

**2. And how to deal with nested map:**

```
nestedMap.key1.nestedKey1=nestedValue1

nestedMap.key1.nestedKey2=nestedValue2

nestedMap.key2.nestedKey3=nestedValue3

nestedMap.key2.nestedKey4=nestedValue4
```

Comment: ```test.feature={UPPER:{id:'54'}}``` it's working perfectly. I want to specify default value if property not configured.

Comment: In this case, try this:

`@Bean
public Map<String, Map<String, String>> test(
    @Value("#{${test.feature:#{T(java.util.Collections).emptyMap()}}}")
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> ids) {

    return ids;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and this works as you wanted it:

```
@Value("#{${test.feature:{T(java.util.Collections).emptyMap()}}}")
Map<String, Map<String, String>> ids) {
return ids;
```

Comment: If I am using this approach, getting IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.

Comment: I see. This could be related to Spring version. I have tested with String Boot 3.1.0